# Передать массив аргументов в func

Tags: golang

Каким образом в golang лучше передавать массив аргументов в ф-цию? структурой, или есть варианты попроще?

Comment: У вас какая-то путаница с понятиями. Массивы и структуры - это разные вещи. Покажите код и что вас в нём не устраивает.

Comment: надо передать в ф-цию параметры,в node я просто бы передал аргументом JSON, в go как я понимаю единственный путь это передать struct, или есть другие пути?

Comment: Ну объявите параметры и передавайте. `func foo(a int, b string) error`.

Comment: а если параметров больше 10? читабельность кода будет не очень, просто хочется понять есть ли какая то best practice для таких задач

Comment: Во-первых, когда у вашей функции столько параметров, пора пересмаривать дизайн. Во-вторых, если вам действительно нужно столько параметров, то да, лучше использовать структуру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Большое количество параметров в функции - это антипаттерн. Исключения составляют разве что конструкторы сложных сущностей. В таком случае можно воспользоваться структурой:

```
type Config struct {
    Logger ...
    Notifier ...
    DB ...
    ...
}

func NewFoo(c Config) (*Foo, error) { 
    ...
}
```

Альтернатива этому - различные паттерны для указания опций, например [описанный Робом Пайком](https://commandcenter.blogspot.ru/2014/01/self-referential-functions-and-design.html). Но к таким вещам стоит прибегать, когда у вас уже очень много динамических опций.

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о переменном числе аргументов, то например так
https://play.golang.org/p/kFOnQKKv1I

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func a(arg1 int, args ...string){
    fmt.Println(arg1)
    for index, val := range args {
        fmt.Println(index, val)
    }
}


func main() {
a(1, "aaa", "bbb")
}
```